# Check if an arrayList contains an array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, contains

I have an arrayList that contains arrays. How do I check if the arrayList contains a specified array? I used `.contains` method and it returns `false` instead of expected `true`.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String[]> action = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        action.add(new String[]{"appple", "ball"});
        String[] items = new String[]{"appple", "ball"};
        if (action.contains(new String[]{"appple", "ball"})) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
        }
        System.out.println(action.contains(items)); // False
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks to be a bad design from the get-go. Consider creating a `List<List<String>>` or wrap the array in a class that uses `java.util.Arrays.equals` and `java.util.Arrays.hashCode` as its own equals and hashCode methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are creating different arrays (even if the contents are the same), contains will result false.

However, if you do this:

```
 List<String[]> action = new ArrayList<String[]>();
 String[] items = new String[]{"apple","ball"};   
 action.add(items);
 if (action.contains(items)) 
     System.out.println("Yes");
```

This will print **Yes**.
Also, some examples of the behaviour:

```
 String[] items = new String[]{"apple","ball"};   
 action.add(items);
 String[] clone = items.clone();
 String[] mirror = items;

 action.contains(clone); // false 
 action.contains(mirror); // true

 items[0]="horse";
 System.out.println(mirror[0]);        // "horse"
 System.out.println(clone[0]);         // "apple"
 System.out.println(action.get(0)[0]); // "horse"

 mirror[1]="crazy";
 System.out.println(clone[1]);         // "ball"
 System.out.println(action.get(0)[1]); // "crazy"
 System.out.println(items[1]);         // "crazy"

 clone[1]="yolo";
 System.out.println(action.get(0)[1]); // "crazy"
 System.out.println(items[1]);         // "crazy"
 System.out.println(mirror[1]);        // "crazy"

 System.out.println(action.get(0).hashCode());    //2018699554
 System.out.println(items.hashCode());            //2018699554
 System.out.println(clone.hashCode());            //1311053135
 System.out.println(mirror.hashCode());           //2018699554
```

---

### *Custom "`contains`"*

The issue here is that if you want to search for an specific array afterwards, you'd lose the references and searching an item wouldn't be possible, not even replicating the array with the same exact values.

As a workaround, you could implement your own `contains` method. Something like:

If you wish to get the index:

```
static int indexOfArray(List<String[]> list, String[] twin)
{        
   for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
      if (Arrays.equals(list.get(i),twin))
           return i;
   return -1;
}
```

And then, call it like:

```
String[] toSearch = new String[]{"apple","ball"};
int index = indexOfArray(action, toSearch); 

if (index>0) 
    System.out.println("Array found at index "+index);
else
    System.out.println("Array not found");
```

If the index is bigger than -1, you can get your original array by just:

```
String[] myArray = action.get(index);
```

---

### ***HashMap + identifier***

An alternative would be storing the arrays into a `HashMap` by declaring an identifier for each array. For example:

***Base64 ID***

This will give the same result for the same values, as the encoded value is based on the entries, not the Object's reference.

```
 static String getIdentifier(String[] array)
 {
    String all="";
    for (String s : array)
        all+=s;
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(all.getBytes());
 }
```

And then you could:

```
Map<String, String[]> arrayMap= new HashMap<>();
String[] items = new String[]{"apple","pear", "banana"}; // *[1234] 
action.add(items);
arrayMap.put(getIdentifier(items), items); // id = QUJDYWFh
//....
//Directly finding the twin will fail
String[] toSearch = new String[]{"apple","pear", "banana"}; // *[1556]
System.out.println(action.contains(toSearch)); // false

//But if we get the identifier based on the values
String arrId = getIdentifier(toSearch); // id = QUJDYWFh
System.out.println(action.contains(arrayMap.get(arrId)));  //true

//arrayMap.get(arrId)->  *[1234]
//.....
```

***Name**.*

Choose a representative name and use it as Id

```
Map<String, String[]> arrayMap= new HashMap<>();
String[] items = new String[]{"apple","pear", "banana"};
action.add(items);
arrayMap.put("fruits", items);
//...
System.out.println(action.contains(arrayMap.get("fruits"))); // true
```

Comment: `The issue here is that if you want to search for an specific array afterwards, you'd lose the references and searching an item wouldn't be possible, not even replicating the array with the same exact values.` Super strange. Where do I read more about this?

Comment: That's exactly what happens in your question. You know which the values are, you replicate the array point by point, and still tells you that it doesn't contain it. It's because your first array's hashcode is 1234 while the second one's is 1554 (simplified). Even with the same values, they're different objects.

Comment: `String[] copy = items.clone()` if you invoke `items.equals(copy)` the result is false. Why? Test it. `System.out.println(copy.hashCode());` and `System.out.println(items.hashCode());` Not the same hashcode, even for a clone.

Comment: @JJ123 https://dzone.com/articles/object-identity-and-equality-in-java

Answer (score 2):

The 'contains' method compares equivalent hashCode values.

So if you make it like below*, it will pass.

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String[]> action = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        String[] items = new String[]{"appple","ball"};
        action.add(items);

        System.out.println("TO STRING");
        System.out.println("--"+action.get(0));
        System.out.println("--"+new String[]{"apple","ball"});

        System.out.println("HASHCODES");
        String[] sameValues = new String[]{"apple","ball"};
        System.out.println("--"+action.get(0).hashCode());    
        System.out.println("--"+items.hashCode());           
        System.out.println("--"+sameValues.hashCode());    
       
        System.out.println("CONTAINS");
        System.out.println("--"+action.contains(items));  // *this
        System.out.println("--"+action.contains(sameValues));
        System.out.println("--"+action.contains(new String[]{"apple","ball"}));
 
    }
}
```

result is:

```
TO STRING
--[Ljava.lang.String;@7b1d7fff
--[Ljava.lang.String;@299a06ac
HASHCODES
--1243554231
--1243554231
--2548778887
CONTAINS
--true
--false
--false
```

---

Regarding the code shown when printing the array, these don't override `toString()`, so you get:

**`getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`**

*For example:*

*`[Ljava.lang.String;@7b1d7fff`*

- **`[`** stands for single dimension array
- **`Ljava.lang.String`** stands for the type
- **`@`**
- **`7b1d7fff`** Hex representation of the hashcode

---

However, if you want to compare the values, there is the following method.

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] items = new String[]{"apple","ball"};

        ArrayList<String> action = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));

        if (action.contains("apple")) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over this list and for each element, i.e. array, call [`Arrays.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) method to check equality of arrays until first match, or till the end of the list if none match. In this case it can return `true` for each element:

```java
List<String[]> list = List.of(
        new String[]{"appple", "ball"},
        new String[]{"appple", "ball"});

String[] act = new String[]{"appple", "ball"};

System.out.println(list.stream()
        .anyMatch(arr -> Arrays.equals(arr, act))); // true
```

This method internally calls [`String#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method for each element of the array, i.e. `String`, so this code also returns `true`:

```java
List<String[]> list = List.of(
        new String[]{new String("appple"), new String("ball")},
        new String[]{new String("appple"), new String("ball")});

String[] act = new String[]{new String("appple"), new String("ball")};

System.out.println(list.stream()
        .anyMatch(arr -> Arrays.equals(arr, act))); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

According to JavaDocs, "contains" method is using "equals" and "hashCode" methods in order to check whether an object is contained.

A leading question:
Do you know what's the implementation of "equals" for arrays?

Check it and you will probably understand your code's execution result (hint: ==).

As "Hovercraft Full Of Eels" said, a better design will be using a list of some Collection which you DO understand / control it's "equals" and "hashCode"  methods.